# Displaying prime numbers between two user defined numbers in C

Tags: c

I get the **error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment** when I run:

```
for(x=2;x<=n/2;x++)
{
     if ((n%x)=0)
     {
        y=1;
      }
 }
```

Comment: `if ((n%x)=0)` with a single `=` you are trying to assign `0` to an expression. You need `==` to check for equality

Comment: if ((n%x)=0), this should be if ((n%x)==0) for comparing.

Comment: change `(n%x)=0` to `(n%x)==0`.

Comment: Your compiler error and warnings should be telling you exactly what the issue is (e.g. `lvalue required`). Always compile with, at minimum, `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string to enable most warnings -- and do not accept code until it compiles without warning. (and **read the warnings**, compilers have gotten quite good at explaining where and what the problem is. You can learn as much C simply by reading, and understanding, the warnings as you can learn anywhere else)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between assignment operator (=) and comparison operator (==). In your code you are comparing so you should use "=="

```
for(x=2;x<=n/2;x++)
{
 if ((n%x)==0)
 {
    y=1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said the problem is in the condition of the `if` statement. Lets say `n = 13`.
It enters the `for` statement.
So the first step would be this:

```
if(1 = 0)//13 % 2 = 1
    y = 1;
```

It's like saying 5 = 9 or 100 = 12 or 5 = 0. Which is impossible.
To check if `n % x` is 0 use `n % x == 0`.

http://www.includehelp.com/c-programming-questions/what-is-difference-between-assignment-and-equalto-operator.aspx